# Importing fonts in email signature

Tags: css, email, fonts, adobe, signature

I want to create a custom email signature using an Adobe font. My mail is hosted by Strato (a German mail server).
I inserted this signature via Apple Mail, unfortunately I found out that the CSS `<style>` part is not included, since apple Mail is just using the `<body>`. Accordingly, I can not import a font.

Is there a way to write my email signature with an external (Adobe) font without it being blocked or downloaded by the recipient?

```
<head>
    <style>
        @import url("https://use.typekit.net/wur3oiu.css");
        body {
            background-color: gray; 
            font-family: pragmatica-extended,sans-serif;
            font-weight: 400;
            font-style: normal;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background: transparent;">
  <div >
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `<link>` tag instead:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/wur3oiu.css" />
```

But be aware that font support is very limited across email clients (see [Can I email](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-at-font-face/)). Also, consider the impact of having to download an entire font file and CSS for every single mail you're going to send.